# ASP.NET coding for insert data

Tags: asp.net

i want sample coding to insert  data into SQL SErver 2005 using ASP.NET

Answer (score 3):

The most basic using a store procedure, but agree with @TomTom you probably need to get a little info on the subject first.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Create", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "foo" 
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Head over to http:/www.asp.net/ and read the tutorials there as well as hang around the beginner forum. This gives you a lot more than some code snippet here.